# setting an ImageView to invisable inside a custom Adapter

Tags: android

i'm defining my own list adapter and i want an image inside it to be shown OR hidden based on a value what i've noticed that its always invisible or visible disregarding the value

Here's my code , this code is inside the getView method

```
singleRow=data.get(position);
     readit = singleRow.getRead();
    Log.i("readit","" + readit );
    //NotificationID=singleRow.getId();
    holder.title.setText(singleRow.getAttach_title());
    holder.date.setText( singleRow.getAttach_created());
    holder.dueDate.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    holder.course.setText(singleRow.getCourse_title());

    if(readit==1)
            {
                //holder.read.setImageResource(IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE);
                holder.read.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
             {
              holder.read.setImageResource(R.drawable.unread);
             }
```

Comment: One more thing , i CAN'T just use setImageResource(1) since it will mess up the whole interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never setting your `read` image back to `VISIBLE` after you once set it to `INVISIBLE`. In `else` you, probably, should have `setVisibility(VISIBLE)`

Comment: thank you its working , but the space is gone and the UI is messed up :(

Comment: you can try GONE instead of INVISIBLE. With INVISIBLE the image becomes invisible but the place it occupies is still there. With GONE it completely goes away. Other than that can't say anything not seeing your XML

Answer (score 1):

```
holder.dueDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: GONE will delete the space and the whole UI will be messed up. i'm using relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.It will solve your problem

```
singleRow=data.get(position);   
    readit = singleRow.getRead();   
        Log.i("readit","" + readit );  
    //NotificationID=singleRow.getId();   
        holder.title.setText(singleRow.getAttach_title());    
        holder.date.setText( singleRow.getAttach_created());  
    holder.dueDate.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);    
        holder.course.setText(singleRow.getCourse_title());  
        holder.read.setImageResource(R.drawable.unread); 

        if(readit==1) {   
        //holder.read.setImageResource(IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE); 
        holder.read.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                    }
```